# About Devi in sleeping position

Tags: identification-request, goddess

[image]

Few days ago, i found that Devi in sleeping position at newly bulit Durga Devi Temple at Batu Caves. I am impressed for that and wanted to ask a question about this.

So, my question is, does any scriptures mention it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Devī known as Yoganidrā. Her pratimā is described by T.A. Gopinath Rao briefly-

> The figure representing this devī is required to be sculptured as lying down on a bed with eyes closed. It must be shaped very beautifully. The devī keeps a drinking vessel near her, and has only two hands. 
> ~ [*Elements of Hindu Iconography* (Vol 1, Part 2, pg. 362)](https://archive.org/details/dBrt_elements-of-hindu-iconography-vol-1-part-2-t.-a.-gopinatha-rao/page/362/mode/2up?view=theater)

Devī Yoganidrā is Mahāmāyā in the svarūpa of Viṣṇu's yoganidrā, as Durgāsaptaśatī ([1.41](https://archive.org/details/piXt_durga-saptashati-with-7-sanskrit-commentaries-and-chandrarabha-hindi-commentary-/page/n225/mode/2up?view=theater)) says-

> tannātravismayaḥ kāryo yoganidrā jagatpateḥ /  
> mahāmāyā hareścaivā tayā sammohyate jagat //

Yoganidrā is tamaḥpradhānā śaktiḥ, as stated in the [commentary Nāgojībhāṭṭī](https://archive.org/details/piXt_durga-saptashati-with-7-sanskrit-commentaries-and-chandrarabha-hindi-commentary-/page/n225/mode/2up?view=theater), being the active principle of māyā in the entire jagat, affecting all jīvas. 
Other [commentaries on Durgāsaptaśatī (1.41)](https://archive.org/details/piXt_durga-saptashati-with-7-sanskrit-commentaries-and-chandrarabha-hindi-commentary-/page/n225/mode/2up?view=theater) also throw light -

> **mahāmāyā** nāma harerīśvarasya **yoganidrā** paramānandamayī śaktiḥ / ~ Caturdharī 
> yataḥ mahāmāyeti yā anādiḥ prasiddhāsti bhagavati 
> eṣā jagatpaterharerviṣṇoryoganidreti kathyate /  ~ Śāntanavī

In Devī Bhāgavata Purāṇa ([1.7.26](https://archive.org/details/DeviBhagavataWithHindiTranslationVolume1GitaPress/page/n107/mode/2up?view=theater)) & Mārkaṇḍeya Purāṇa ([78.49-52](https://archive.org/details/SriMarkandeyaMahaPuranaBhashyaTikaChowkhambaVIdyaBhavan/page/n413/mode/2up?view=theater)), Brahmā does stavana of Devī Yoganidrā herself, when he is unable to wake up Viṣṇu from nidrā, in order to seek his aid.
The first śloka of tantroktaṁ rātrisūktam (i.e. Mārkaṇḍeya Purāṇa [78.53](https://archive.org/details/SriMarkandeyaMahaPuranaBhashyaTikaChowkhambaVIdyaBhavan/page/n413/mode/2up?view=theater)) refers to Yoganidrā -

> viśveśvarīṁ jagaddhātrīṁ sthitisaṁhārakāriṇīm / 
> nidrāṁ bhagavatīṁ viṣṇoratulāṁ tejasaḥ prabhuḥ //